# binary to decimal program isn't giving correct answer java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

So i have to write a program for homework where it takes a binary number and prints out its the decimal form. I've tried and and i just can't really get it. Like im printing out what it's doing every time in the loop and it looks like im getting the wrong value when i multiply the inputed data by the 2^i. If someone could help, that would be amazing

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a binary number (only 1's or 0's): ");
        String binary_number = userinput.next();

        int value = 0;
        int square_value = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < binary_number.length(); i++) {


            char binary_place_holder = binary_number.charAt(i); 
            square_value = (int) Math.pow(2, i);

            if (binary_place_holder == '1') {
                value =  (square_value*binary_place_holder+value);
            }
            System.out.println(binary_place_holder+ "  " + square_value + "  " + value); 

        }
        System.out.print(binary_number + " == " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: binary_place_holder is a string, what would you expect square_value * (string) + value to equal? Try converting binary_place_holder to an integer and change your if to check == `1` rather than `'1'`

Comment: `binary_place_holder` is a char, which is the reason why it's being compiled at all. Anyway, since `binary_place_holder` will (should) represent a 1 any time passing the condition, the multiplication can be omitted. If not, you will multiply `square_value`by 49 which is the decimal value of char '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you determine the exponent is wrong: The exponent is not `i`.

You need to realize that you are looking at the string from left to right side so from the highest bit. 
This means the first character's exponent is `2^string_length-1`.
Second character's exponent is `2^string_length-2` and so on. 
Therefore as the index `i` becomes larger, i.e. as we are scanning the input left to right, the exponent value becomes smaller.

So the exponent is:

```
int exponent = binary_number.length() - 1 - i;
```

*Note*: You can of course do things in reverse and start from the end of the input string and determine the exponent that way, I just wanted to do less changes to your code.

---

Also, you should add a check to make sure the input is a valid binary number. You can write your own function to do it but a simpler solution is to use regex matching:

```
binary_number.matches("[01]+")
```

This will return true if the string `binary_number` contains only `'0'` and `'1'` characters, and false otherwise.

---

Applying all these changes to your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a binary number (only 1's or 0's): ");
    String binary_number = userinput.next();

    if(!binary_number.matches("[01]+")) {
        System.err.println("\nPlease enter a valid binary number");
    } else {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary_number.length(); i++) {
            if (binary_number.charAt(i) == '1') {
                int exponent = binary_number.length() - 1 - i;
                value += (int) Math.pow(2, exponent);
            } 
        }
        System.out.print(binary_number + " == " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java uses Unicode, not ASCII. 48 is the one (for some characters, two are required) UTF-16 code unit value for '0', a 16-bit number.

Comment: @TomBlodget you are correct. That part was extra anyway so I just removed it :)

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped a lot. I just couldn't figure out what i was doing wrong and i didn't know it was with my exponent value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered cheating but you could go all like

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(binary_number, 2));
```